# returning an NSObject - bad exec

Tags: xcode, ios, return, nsobject

I've been struggling with a problem that I hope someone can help me with.

I have Class called 'GameObjectDefinitionTable', where I set all my object properties, which is in another class called 'Product'. In my 'HelloWorldScene' I allocate 'GameObjectDefinitionTable' which in turn creates several 'Product's. Like this:

HelloWorldScene -> GameObjectDefinitionTable -> Product

I then want to return a 'Product' to 'HelloWorldScene. But here is where I get problems. Some code:

**HelloWorldScene:**

```
GameObjectDefinitionTable *god = [[GameObjectDefinitionTable alloc]init];
Product* currentProduct = [god getProductWithNum:0];
NSLog(@"currenProduct (name): %@",currentProduct.name); //Crash
```

**GameObjectDefinitionTable:**

```
-(void) createProducts {
    Product *product;

    for (int i=0; i<[allProductsWithDefinitions count];i++ ) {  
        product = [[Product alloc]init];
        product.name = [[allProductsWithDefinitions objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:0];
        product.density = [[[allProductsWithDefinitions objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:1] floatValue];
        product.scoreValue = [[[allProductsWithDefinitions objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:2] intValue];
        product.fileName = [[allProductsWithDefinitions objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:3];
        [products addObject:product];   
        [product release];
    }

    [allProductsWithDefinitions release];
}

-(Product *) getProductWithNum:(int)tNum {
    Product *tempProduct;
    tempProduct = [products objectAtIndex:tNum];

    return tempProduct;
    [tempProduct release]; 
}
```

The arrays and all in 'GameObjectDefinitionTable' is working fine if I log in that class.

Would be really grateful for an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it the case you need something like:

```
- (Product *)getProductWithNum:(int)tNum
{
  Product *tempProduct = [[products objectAtIndex:tNum] retain];
  return [tempProduct autorelease];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> `Product *tempProduct;`
>
> `tempProduct = [products objectAtIndex:tNum];`
>
> `return tempProduct;`
>
> `[tempProduct release];`

Is that what you mean to have?  You kind of have two big problems cancelling each other out here.  The `[tempProduct release];` line is unreachable.  The second, if you were to actually execute `[tempProduct release];` before the return, you would be releasing the memory, and then accessing the `currentProduct.name` property of what is essentially a dangling pointer.  This illegal memory access could cause your Bad Exec.

Since you are not allocating, copying, or retaining `tempProduct`, you **must NOT** release it.  Why not just a simple `return [products objectAtIndex:tNum];`?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think that petert solved it for me :)